# Using momentjs / lodash, how can I add days / weeks between 2 dates?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I have a start date (a Sunday) and an end date (a Saturday), I want to create an array with all of the Sundays between them.

Here's what I have so far:

```
weeks = [{
      start: startDate,
      end: angular.copy(startDate).add(6, 'days')
    }];

    while(_.last(weeks).end <= endDate) {
      weeks.push({
        start: angular.copy(_.last(weeks)).start.add(7, 'days'),
        end: angular.copy(_.last(weeks)).end.add(7, 'days')
      })
    }
```

This feels very messy and also, it's somehow wrong. It's adding multiple days when it should only be adding one. I don't particular care about the `end` date, but if I can get it, I'll take it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a simple solution built on a while loop. I think lodash syntax only complicates the matter in this case.

Start with the first Sunday and repeatedly add 7 days until you pass the ending Saturday. Push clones of the moment object into an array. If you don't clone, you end up with a list of the same date as you continue to reference a single moment object, in this case `start`.

```
var start =  moment('2016-09-18'); //last sunday
var finish = moment('2016-10-29'); //saturday in october

// an array of moment objects
var sundays = [start.clone()]; // include the first sunday

// foreach additional sunday, clone it into an array
while(start.add(7, 'days').isBefore(finish)) {
  sundays.push(start.clone());
}
```

Comment: is `.clone` a moment thing?

Comment: Yes, `.clone` is a function of the moment object. For reference sake, here it is in the source - https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/e90e864617d3c501c2eaa1119392781c58a2ce63/moment.js#L2953-L2955